# Should I contribute to an open source project with a private account or one tied to my corporate identity?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

While working on a software project for my company, I came across an open source library for our language of choice, that does *almost* everything I need.
I thought about submitting changes with the couple of (small) additional features we need to this open source project, features that I think might be beneficial for the "general public", not just for my specific case.
But a question came to my mind: should I do this with my personal GitHub account, or should I open a new one, tied to my work email?

Honestly, if it wasn't for this particular project that I'm working on right now, I would probably have never come across this library, and would never have needed to expand its functionality. Additionally, the work I would be doing on it would be during my working hours, so paid by the company.

On the other hand, I don't know if I want this work to be permanently tied to my "work identity": I'd rather  the contributions be shown as "name.surname@popularfreeemailservice.com" instead of "name.surname@fairlyfamouscompany.com".
Additionally, if I ever quit my current company (even though right now I have no intention at all to do it, it might still happen at some point in the future), I might lose access to this GitHub account (as I will of course lose access to my corporate email address). And, who knows, I might want to contribute to this open source project again in the future, or it might be interesting to show it in the future to some company to which I applied (as some like to ask for the applicant'S GitHub account to see their open source contributions).

Is there some industry standard/best practice that I'm not aware of regarding this? If not, how should I proceed?

By the way, I don't think my boss would care much either way, so this is pretty much my decision to make.

Comment: Do you have explicit, written permission from your employer to open source the contributions you are going to make?

Comment: @PhilipKendall my company's primary business isn't IT, so no, there are no written conditions about this on the contract or anywhere else. We are a small team of in-house developers in a much bigger infrastructure. Not only open source software development, but software development in general isn't something my company is very familiar with at all outside of my team.

Comment: All of which increases the risk _to you_ if you do this without getting explicit permission from your employer.

Comment: You can change the registered email of a GitHub account. So you actually won't lose access to an account registered to your work email account.

Comment: Does your employer want its name tied to your contributions? Will they take responsibility for your contributions after you are gone? There is a difference between "Contribution by mrodo" and "Contribution by mrodo from Acme Corp"

Comment: @SethR I don't think my employer cares much either way, so no, I don't expect that they would want to "take responsibility" of a couple of commits on a public GitHub repo. Not that there's much "responsibility" involved in it at all anyway, the way I see it...

Comment: You can associate multiple email addresses with a single GitHub account. When contributing to open source projects on behalf of my employer, I always make sure that my commits are created using my work email address. However, my employer has explicit rules for open source contributions (and a contract addendum for this), and a process for asking permission to contribute to a specific project.

Answer (score 5):

Beware of assuming anything. Your contract probably includes a clause that says that anything you create on company time or using company resources belongs to the company.

If that applies, then don't open source anything without approval. Let the company decide whether or not to do it under their name.

If the work is entirely yours, do it under your own name.

Comment: _"If the work is entirely yours, do it under your own name."_ Exactly - doing it under your name in your free time is also important in terms of attribution.

Answer (score 1):

> But a question came to my mind: should I do this with my personal GitHub account, or should I open a new one, tied to my work email?

My thoughts: use your personal account and do it on your personal time.

Some folks will bring up the NDA clause that may say whatever work you do on company's time is owned by the company. That isn't the case here. You discovered the inner workings of the open source code that may benefit anyone else who uses the code. That is different despite the fact that your contributions wouldn't have been made otherwise had you not used it at work. Now if your contribution is proprietary or reveals some insider information, then that needs to be brought up with the company before you make such a contribution and it may need the company's information.

If I had to make a wild guess, I would say a vast majority of open source contributions to source codes like PHP, or Firefox are a direct result of someone using it while at work and discovering you know this feature or this change would make a huge difference. Matter of fact, many speakers at the Drupal speak I went to would talk about how they were working at a company and discovered and made these contributions and it was simply their name as the sole contributor. Very doubtful someone sitting at home one day would ponder on some random thing that they think would help.

The wording have to be carefully considered though: I was working on open source project X while at company Y. During that time I discovered some improvements to open source project X by doing Z. I believed in this project so much that I dedicated some of my free time to improve the code base.

Comment: That clause is usually not part of the NDA, but rather of the employment contact. Or, as in Poland, part of labor law.